# Issue while reading csv file using pandas

Tags: pandas

While importing data from csv file with pandas, the output is coming embedded in double quotation as show below.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
health_data = pd.read_csv("Data_File.csv", header=0, sep='[,]', engine='python')

CSV file 
[Refer csv file here ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJfoB.png)

output:

"Duration Average_Pulse Max_Pulse  Calorie_Burnage  Hours_Work Hours_Sleep"
0        "30            80       120            240.0        10.0           7"
1        "45            85       120            250.0        10.0           7"
2        "45            90       130            260.0         8.0           7"
3        "60            95       130            270.0         8.0           7"
4        "60           100       140            280.0         0.0           7"
5          "           NaN       NaN              NaN         NaN            "
6        "60           105       140            290.0         7.0           8"
7        "60           110       145            300.0         7.0           8"
8        "45           NaN        AF              NaN         8.0           8"
9        "45           115       145            310.0         8.0           8"
10       "60           120       150            320.0         0.0           8"
11       "60         9 000       130              NaN         NaN           8"
12       "45           125       150            330.0         8.0           8"
```

Problem:
You can see in output the each row is embedded in double quotations and not able to convert into other datatypes.

I want output without embedded in quote like shown below:
Duration Average_Pulse Max_Pulse  Calorie_Burnage  Hours_Work Hours_Sleep
0        30            80       120            240.0        10.0           7
1        45            85       120            250.0        10.0           7
2        45            90       130            260.0         8.0           7
3        60            95       130            270.0         8.0           7

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Note that what you have does not have multiple columns; it has one column of values which have commas in them which will be output as a double quote enclosed value in the csv file. You'll need to read it in line by line, strip the `"`s and split the lines on `,` to get the values into your df.

Answer (score 0):

In `read_csv` change the sep to:

```
sep=','
```

without brackets

Comment: This works but I'm not getting desired output.  Output is coming as below which is not in row and columns format  Duration,Average_Pulse,Max_Pulse,Calorie_Burnage,Hours_Work,Hours_Sleep
0                                  30,80,120,240,10,7
1                                  45,85,120,250,10,7
2                                   45,90,130,260,8,7
3                                   60,95,130,270,8,7
4                                  60,100,140,280,0,7
5                                               ,,,,,

Comment: It is hard to help with an image of the data. Please open the CSV in a text editor and copy to your question above a sample

Comment: I found the issue. The data I have downloaded are embedded in quotation but its not showing in csv file. When i open in Notepad I found it. Thank you @Nick